# Vertical Spacing in ESC/POS

Tags: escpos

I'm printing an adhesive label (6x5cm) with a printer model 3nStar RPT006.

In the adhesive I am printing a title, QR code and the QR code in text

something like this

My Title

▄

qr code

Using [this](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php/blob/f414320fc510afcacd4cbb75902f827399dee429/src/Mike42/Escpos/Printer.php) class as reference, I'm doing something like this:

```js
initialize(),
setJustification(Printer.JUSTIFY_CENTER),
'My Title',
feed(),
qr(qrText),
feed(),
qrText,
feed(2),
cut(Printer.CUT_FULL, 1),
```

My problem is: I don't know how to control the vertical size, or how to set the height of the paper. Between each label I have a gap of 3mm.

So my question is, how should I handle the vertical spacing/height?

Currently I very close to get a perfect label, but seems like the printed label is some millimeters shorter and each time I print a label, it miss a little bit more, so there is a time where I start to cut the adhesive part and not the gap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible in your environment, but there are three options.

- Prepare blank image data with the required number of vertical dots and print it([graphics(EscposImage $image, $size)](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php#graphicsescposimage-image-size)) instead of the line feed code.
- Use [setLineSpacing($height)](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php#setlinespacingheight) to change the height of one line only for the required part and start a new line. Then return to the original size.
- Make your own customization by adding the function to feed the paper in dot units to the library for printing.
  [ESC J](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=15)